# Yii SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, pdo, yii

I have looked at the other questions concerning this error message, but all appear to have something to do with a miss match between a parameter and its binding, or missing bindings, or something like that.  Here is my code.  Can anyone here see the error?  This is in a CDbMigration class.

```
$this->insert('company', array(
    'name' => 'Site Administrator',
    ));
$companyId = $this->dbConnection->getLastInsertID();

$sql  = 'insert into `user` (`company-id`, `login-id`, `password`) ';
$sql .= 'values (:company-id, :login-id, :password)';
$command = $this->dbConnection->createCommand($sql);
$command->bindValue(':company-id', $companyId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$command->bindValue(':login-id', 'admin');
$command->bindValue(':password', 'admin');
$command->execute();
```

The first insert performs properly, the second gives the following error:

```
Exception: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined. The SQL statement executed was: insert into `user` (`company-id`, `login-id`, `password`) values (:company-id, :login-id, :password). Bound with :company-id='6', :login-id='admin', :password='admin' (C:\eclipse-php-3.0.2\workspace\interview\lib\yii\db\CDbCommand.php:357)
```

For the record, I realize that I need to do something to the password so that it is not stored in plain text.  I will deal with that later.  In addition, the user table is defined in the migration class as follows:

```
$this->createTable('user', array(
    'id' => 'pk',
    'company-id' => 'integer not null',
    'login-id' => 'string unique not null',
    'password' => 'string not null',
    'full-name' => 'string',
    'mobile-phone' => 'string',
    'other-phone' => 'string',
    'email' => 'string unique',
    ));
$this->addForeignKey('fk_user_company', 'user', 'company-id', 'company', 'id'
    , 'restrict');
```

Comment: Why the down vote on a now 4 year old question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not continue in the same way and have:

```
$this->insert('user', array(
   'company-id' => (int)$companyId,
   'login-id' => 'admin',
   'password' => 'admin'
));
```

?

Also, using dashes instead of underscores is not the best idea you have had for a table column name. 
Later you'll want to use CActiveRecord to reference the login id for example, but

```
$model->login-id;
```

is invalid so you'd have to

```
$model->{'login-id'} // or
$model->getAttribute('login-id');
```

which is a pain. Overall i advise you to switch it to underscore.

Comment: Unfortunately I started in that way, and it gives the same error, but I did not use (int).  I will try to shift the dashes to underscores.  Maybe that is part of the issue under the covers.  I do know that the error is thrown by the PDO execute function when coding as you have above.

Comment: It looks like the dashes in my field names was the issue.  I replaced them with underscores, and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to Yii documentation:

> SQL data type of the parameter. If null, the type is determined by the PHP type of the value.

So:

```
$command->bindValue(':company-id', $companyId);
```

Or

```
$command->bindValue(':company-id', (int)$companyId);
```

Should works

Comment: I tried $command->bindValue(':company-id', $companyId); with the same results.